# how to download file in express js with AJAX post request

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

how to download file from express js what i am trying at server side is:

```
router.post('/download',function(req,res){    
    var file = __dirname + '/'+req.body.path;
    console.log(file);
    res.download(file); // Set disposition and send it.
});
```

I am getting my file in response how to download it in angular side

Comment: provide your directory structure

Comment: I'm pretty sure the file has to be in a directory that is public facing. `res.download('path/to/public/file/on/your/server')` so you might want to write the file to a public directory. see http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download

Comment: '/home/Desktop/KRA-GIT/public/uploads/vss830/1478062963587-mongo.jpg' is the path , now i am getting file in response

Comment: try putting that here https://gyazo.com/e22cff27547e6f04ca7afc48ab38ca88 see if your path is correct

Comment: solved by changin in HTML<a ng-href="{{(doc.fileMeta.path).split('/').slice(1).join('/')}}" 
                           download="{{(doc.fileMeta.filename).split('-').slice(1).join('-')}}"
                           data-toggle="tooltip" 
                           title="Download" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-download" 
                           aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>

Answer (score 0):

another approach

```
router.get('/download:file',function(req,res){    
var file = __dirname + '/'+req.params.file;
res.download(file);
});


<a ng-href="/download/{{Filename}}" target="_blank">Download
</a>
```

Comment: Would this work for a file then browser could render, eg an image or text file?